# Make a DIV 100 % when I use jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm a little new to use jquery but I was thinking give it a go to try something "simple"
I have got it to work but the problem I have is the DIV does not go 100 % in width and also not in heigh when I try to see the page.

I did try to see the error when I add a yellow background in the div and I can see the div is 100 % but still the page that load inside the DIV is not.
So it feels like that is not a CSS error but more then a JS error.

The code is not nice but it almost work and that I trying to do is change the pages with a tiny keyboard I have with 6 buttons.

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <style>
    body {
      height: 100vh;
      width: 100vw;
      margin: 0px;
      padding: 0px;
    }
    #div1 {
      background-color: yellow;
      height: 100vh;
      width: 100vw;
    }
    </style>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      document.onkeydown = function(e){
         e = e || window.event;
         var key = e.which || e.keyCode;
         if(key===65){
           $("#div1").html('<object data="http://adress1">');
         }
         if(key===66){
           $("#div1").html('<object data="http://adress2">');
         }
         if(key===67){
           $("#div1").html('<object data="https://adress3">');
         }
         if(key===68){
           $("#div1").html('<object data="https://adress4">');
         }
      }
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
     <div id="div1">Test</div> 
    </body>
    </html>
```

It maybe have to do something about the object data but not sure.

Comment: Sorry about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will try to answer with what i understood of your question.

I think what you are trying to achieve is to load external pages inside your `div` at the same size of your `div`. It is not working because you don't have CSS on your `object` HTML tag inserted inside the page.

Based on your code, just add the `object` selector in your css :

```
body, object {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
```

Working example :

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<head>
  <style>
    body, object {
      height: 100vh;
      width: 100vw;
      margin: 0px;
      padding: 0px;
    }
    
    #div1 {
      background-color: yellow;
      height: 100vh;
      width: 100vw;
    }
  </style>
  <script>
    document.onkeydown = function(e) {
      e = e || window.event;
      var key = e.which || e.keyCode;
      if (key === 65) {
        $("#div1").html('<object data="https://css-tricks.com">');
      }
      if (key === 66) {
        $("#div1").html('<object data="https://mongoosejs.com">');
      }
      if (key === 67) {
        $("#div1").html('<object data="https://symfony.com">');
      }
      if (key === 68) {
        $("#div1").html('<object data="https://jquery.com">');
      }
    }
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="div1">click a - b - c - d</div>
</body>
```

Comment: ahh I know it was something simple but I did not see it.
Now it working like I want it to do and I understand what you mean.
Thanks alot.

Answer (score 0):

- You want to set 100% height and width of the `div` as per browser's height and width
- You need to set with of the tag which you wanted to load inside that div.
- Its CSS related thing, in below example, I have used `img` to visualize presentation
- And just applied `#div1 img` in stand of `#div1` in class declaration

Please check below code:

```js
document.onkeydown = function (e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    var key = e.which || e.keyCode;
    if (key === 65) {
        console.log('Key : ' + key);
        $("#div1").html('<img src="https://picsum.photos/200/200?random&time=1538825643321" />');
    }
    if (key === 66) {
        console.log('Key : ' + key);
        $("#div1").html('<img src="https://picsum.photos/200/200?random&time=1538825643322" />');
    }
    if (key === 67) {
        console.log('Key : ' + key);
        $("#div1").html('<img src="https://picsum.photos/200/200?random&time=1538825643323" />');
    }
    if (key === 68) {
        console.log('Key : ' + key);
        $("#div1").html('<img src="https://picsum.photos/200/200?random&time=1538825643324" />');
    }
}
```

```css
body{
    background-color: #808080;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}
#div1 img{
    background-color: yellow;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p>Press : a, b, c or d</p>
<div id="div1">Test</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the replay. with the object in the CSS like ElJackiste I got it to work now :)